# Is it permitted to having intercourse with an minor concubine?

Tags: sex, slavery

In some hadiths( I can't find the references, a friend of mine said..), our prophet (pbuh) allowed sahabas to have penetration with infant slaves who haven't reached their first period. Here, penetration with a minor will result in blood coming out and a massacre.

My question is, it was allowed then to have intercourse with minor sex slaves? Here they would have health issues. The hadith-

> بَاب اسْتِبْرَاءِ الْأَمَةِ
>
> أَخْبَرَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ الْمُبَارَكِ عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ عَبْدِ
> الْوَاحِدِ عَنْ الْأَوْزَاعِيِّ قَالَ سَأَلْتُ الزُّهْرِيَّ عَنْ
> الرَّجُلِ يَبْتَاعُ الْجَارِيَةَ لَمْ تَبْلُغْ الْمَحِيضَ وَلَا
> تَحْمِلُ مِثْلُهَا كَمْ يَسْتَبْرِئُهَا قَالَ ثَلَاثَةَ أَشْهُرٍ
> [Ad Darimi](https://www.hadithbd.com/hadith/link/?id=81495)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sexual intercourse with a female is not permitted unless she is safe from harm or injury. Sex is only permitted with a woman who is physically mature enough to have intercourse without suffering harm.

> إن الاستمتاع بالأمة أو الزوجة الصغيرة جائز بما لا يضر بها، فإن كان الوطء أو الاستمتاع يضر بها لم يجز
>
> Intimacy with a slave concubine or a wife who is young is permitted when it will not harm her. And if sexual intercourse or intimacy will harm her then it is not permitted
>
> <sup>— [islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/296044/)</sup>

While a master has several rights over his slave, he does not have the right to kill or injure the slave or to cause her to lose some bodily function. This is well known and evident from ahadith such as:

> من قتل عبده قتلناه ومن جدعه جدعناه ومن أخصاه أخصيناه
>
> Whoever kills his slave, we will kill him: whoever mutilates (his slave). We will mutilate him, and whoever castrates (his slave), we will castrate him.
>
> <sup>— [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:4736)</sup>

As for the 'hadith' whose text you have quoted:

- This is not a hadith or saying of the Prophet ﷺ. Rather it is a saying of Al-Zuhri, who is a Tabi'i.
- This does not say what you claim. Rather it says that al-Awza'i asked Al-Zuhri about the period of istibra of a slave who does not menstruate and those like her do not become pregnant. And that al-Zuhri  stated that it is three months.

Istibra is a waiting period that is observed on receiving ownership over a slave, or before selling her, or after death of the owner or when it is feared that the slave might have committed Zina. It is especially observed before having sexual intercourse or even before non-penetrative intimacy. It is done to ensure that the slave is not already pregnant with someone else's child and that ownership over her is valid and that she is not an Umm Walad of someone else.

Istibra is similar to iddah and is observed by waiting for only one menstrual cycle (or delivery for those pregnant) as that is enough to prove that the womb is empty.

The question here is about the istibra of a woman who does not have any menstrual periods, this could be because she has not yet undergone puberty in full so that her body has developed but menstrual discharge has not yet begun. Or it could be because she suffers from delayed puberty signs because of some illness or genetics. This is a similar case to what is stated in the Quran regarding the iddah of a free wife:

> واللائي يئسن من المحيض من نسائكم إن ارتبتم فعدتهن ثلاثة أشهر واللائي لم يحضن
>
> And those who no longer expect menstruation among your women - if you doubt, then their period is three months, and [also for] those who have not menstruated.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 65:4](https://quran.com/65/4?translations=20)</sup>

On this matter (i.e. slave concubines) there are different madhabs, and this athar states that al-Zuhri's opinion was that the istibra is equal to the iddah period, i.e. three months.